# is it possible to inject background property in the margin of a block element?

Tags: css

demo:https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/BaBJjqe

I have seen that the css box model include margin as the most outter component of the box model. I am wondering if it is possible to add a background color in the margin of a box element.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center; 
  
  background:orange;
  height: 30px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  
  margin:50px;
  
  /* to illustrate what I would accomplish */
  margin-background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div> I am a div </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet?

Comment: @Riddell thanks for answering and sure, there you go, I have edited my post :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are simply looking for box-shadow:

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center; 
  
  background:orange;
  height: 30px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  
  margin:50px;
  
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50px pink;
}
```

```html
<div> I am a div </div>
```

Comment: Nice, easy approach!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this with a margin, and I see that you've already used `border` which would be the obvious one to use for what you're asking for.

Other options to achieve the kind of effect you're looking for include:

- `box-shadow`
- `outline`
- `::before` and `::after`

Each of these works quite differently, but they could all pull off the effect you've asked for, namely an additional coloured shell around a box, outside of the border.

If you want other background effects such as background images, however, your options are probably limited to using `::before` and `::after`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change background color of `margin` property. I'd prefer to go down the root of wrapping the element in a container that respects your margin instead abusing other properties and pseudo styles. This supports all browsers.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: orange;
  height: 30px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>I am a div </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible (as other answers pointed out), but you could keep what you're doing with use of the `::before` (or `::after`) pseudo

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: orange;
  height: 30px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 100px);
  height: calc(100% + 100px);
  left: -50px;
  top: -50px;
  background: pink;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
</div>
```

Comment: note that display:block is not mandatory as you are already using position:absolute

Comment: I've always added that - a habit I picked up as I've defined pseudo elements for different use cases.  But, yeah, I could lose that.